# My container with max-width: 960px doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css, containers

I want to make a navbar with the following code:

```
<nav>
  <ul class ="container"> 
   <li class = "ul--wrap"><a class = "p p__li" href="index.php?page=home">Home</a></li>
   <li class = "ul--wrap"><a class = "p p__li" href="index.php?page=activities">Activities</a></li>
   <li class = "ul--wrap"><a class = "p p__li" href="index.php?page=locations">Locations</a></li>
   <li class = "ul--wrap"><a class = "p p__li"href="index.php?page=register">Register</a></li>
   <li class = "ul--wrap"><button class = "btn"><a class = "p p__li p__li--light" href="index.php?page=tickets">Tickets</a></button></li>                   
         </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to have a container so the navbar doesn't extend the width of 960px. 
I have this container code:

```
.container{
    max-width: 96rem;
    vertical-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

When I want to change the space between the `<li>` items, the `<li>` items extend the 960px centered container.

Comment: You do realise that by default `1rem = 16px`. So `96rem != 960px`? Should be `60rem`

Comment: Why have you given style to your <ul> class when you can give style to your <nav> class if you don't want the navbar to extend width of 960px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem lies with the `max-width` property in the `.container` CSS property you have created.

As pointed out in the comments by @Jones - `1rem = 16px`

Change your CSS to:

```
.container{
    max-width: 60rem;
    vertical-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```